# Set div width by text length

Tags: jquery, html, size, font-size

I made this jquery:

Define the holder div:

```
var cimHolder = componentWrapper.find('.cim_holder');
```

If  title exist data equals title:

```
    if(data.attr('title') != undefined && !isEmpty(data.attr('title'))){
                cimData = data.attr('title');
                cimExist = true;

        }
```

If title exists show it in the div:

```
        if(cimExist){
            cimHolder.css('width', 'auto');//reset
            cimHolder.html(cimData);
```

Set the div widht by character length:

```
            var hossz = cimData.length*6.5;
            //console.log(cimData);
            if(parseInt(cimHolder.css('width'), 10)>200){
                cimHolder.css('width', hossz+'px');
            }
            }
```

But by this way if you get a lot of wide characters, the div will be small, but when you get a lot of narrow characters it will be long. How to fix this?

EDIT: if I set the div auto or 100% it will not fit by the text, just use all the space in the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use

```
overflow:visible;
```

That way it always has to match the width of the containing text, no matter how long.

Answer (score 2):

inline elements like span or a -tags  (`display: inline;`) are only as wide as their content. If you have a block element like a div (`display: block;`) the width is 100% by default. so if you don't need a block element, you can use display: inline;

Has you log the value of `parseInt(cimHolder.css('width'), 10)` ? Maybe the "px" unit can not be parsed correctly.

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use these two css properties:

```
max-width: 100px;
min-width: 50px;
```